# which part of FireBase Admin SDK private key is secret?

Tags: private-key, firebase-admin

When I `generate new private key` from Firebase Admin SDK page, it says the key *contains* secret information. Which parts of it are secret? The `private_key` obviously is, the `.*_ur[il]` obviously aren't. How about the others? Do I need to protect the other fields, like `client_id`, `private_key_id` and `client_email`? Can I publish them in the repo? It would be much easier to handle if I only need to safekeep the `private_key` field. I can read the field and insert it into a const object declared in the program source.

Comment: It is good practice not to publish the service account credentials. There is a lot of sensitive information in that file.

Comment: If you're going to read the private key from a secured location, why not simply extend that logic to read the whole json string from a secured location?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka I agree, but I hope to reduce the amount of secret to a minimum. Actually it is easier to handle the whole stuff as a black box, but it seems to me that only the private key entry is secret.